# separate the message from the server in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

i start a client project in c# and server in c++ (tcp) i get the message from the server and i need in the client side to separate the data and i dont know how to do that

in c++ i did it like that:

```
string getStringPartFromSocket(SOCKET sc, int bytesNum)
{
    char* s = getPartFromSocket(sc, bytesNum, 0);
    string res(s);
    return res;
}

char* getPartFromSocket(SOCKET sc, int bytesNum, int flags)
{
    if (bytesNum == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    char* data = new char[bytesNum + 1];
    int res = recv(sc, data, bytesNum, flags);
    data[bytesNum] = 0;
    return data;
}
```

someone can help me and show me how can i do that in #c?

example:  message = "20008username08password"
result = 200 08 username 08 password

Comment: Terminate the message with a character like "\" when sending so you can separate when receiving.

Comment: Do your messages follow a certain protocol? (On top of TCP ...)